# How to specialize a variadic template function in c++?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, c++20, specialization

Let the function foo be given with the following "signature":

```
template<typename ...Ts>
void foo(Ts ...args)
```

This is a bit overdone since I need foo to proccess `double`s only. How can I modify foo so it accepts `double`s only?

[The original code has been Godbolted:](https://godbolt.org/z/18hzTM)

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<typename ...Ts>
void foo(Ts ...args)
{
    std::tuple<Ts...> tu(args...);
    std::apply([](Ts const&... tupleArgs)
        {
            ((std::cout << tupleArgs << " "), ...);
        }, tu);
}

int main()
{
    foo(-2.44, -5.66, 78.99);
}
```

The output reads:

-2.44 -5.66 78.99

Comment: What C++ standard? C++20 adds nice syntax for it.

Comment: I use the following standard: C++20

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can constrain your template like this:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
requires std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<double, Ts>...>
void foo(Ts ...args)
{
  // ...
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YdrEWK)

As pointed out by HolyBlackCat, you can write the template much more conveniently like this:

```
void foo(std::same_as<double> auto ...args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args);
}
```

Note also that you can use a fold expression to print the arguments.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3EfKMz).

Comment: Even fancier syntax: `void foo(std::same_as<double> auto ...args)`. Also the printing can be done without the tuple, as `((std::cout << args << " "), ...) << '\n';`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh, that's really nice. It would only work for literal-types though, because of the `auto`, right? Also, this is is a substantively different answer. Why not write it up?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I agree: it is a nice answer. Why not write it up? Here is the code: https://godbolt.org/z/3xhqad

Comment: @cigien, There's no type restriction. The `auto` is just there as part of the shorthand concepts syntax so that the reader can tell it's a template at a glance. I'll also toss in that there's a good chance `std::convertible_to` would be more useful than `std::same_as` unless you're set on removing implicit conversions.

Comment: @chris Yeah, you're right, I misread that comment. I think `same_as` is what the OP wants. At least they haven't indicated that they're ok with accepting a bunch of `int`s for example.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the tip. I went ahead and added that to the answer, it's a much cleaner solution.

Comment: You do not need to use `std::conjunction_v` in a requires clause. a regular fold expression works just fine. `requires (... && std::is_same_v<double, Ts>)`.

Comment: @AndyG That's a good point. But I think I'll leave the `conjunction` in there, because it's not very well known. Also, the second version is better anyway, and it also shows an example of a fold-expression.

Answer (score 2):

Those of us who are still stuck with C++17 will have to do with a slightly uglier syntax :(

```
template<typename ...Ts>
std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<Ts, double>...>> foo(Ts ...args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args);
}
```

Comment: You can still use a fold expression inside the definition in C++17. See my answer for how to do that.